# spring rabbitmq get all replies to a fanout message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

The following class in included into several consumer applications:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class HealthListener {

    public static final String HEALTH_CHECK_QUEUE_NAME = "healthCheckQueue";
    public static final String HEALTH_CHECK_FANOUT_EXCHANGE_NAME = "health-check-fanout";


    @Bean
    public Binding healthListenerBinding(
            @Qualifier("healthCheckQueue") Queue queue,
            @Qualifier("instanceFanoutExchange") FanoutExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange instanceFanoutExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(HEALTH_CHECK_FANOUT_EXCHANGE_NAME, true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue healthCheckQueue() {
        return new Queue(HEALTH_CHECK_QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = HEALTH_CHECK_QUEUE_NAME)
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "some result";
    }

}
```

I'm trying to send a message to fanout exchange, and receive all replies, to know which consumers are running.

I can send a message and get the first reply like this:

```
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate template;

// ...
String firstReply = template.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("health-check-fanout", "", "", ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class));
```

However I need to get all repliest to this message, not just the first one. I need to set up a reply listener, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(convertS|s)endAndReceive.*()` methods are not designed to handle multiple replies; they are strictly one request/one reply methods.

You would need to use a `(convertAndS|s)end()` method to send the request, and implement your own reply mechanism, perhaps using a listener container for the replies, together with some component to aggregate the replies.

You could use something like a Spring Integration Aggregator for that, but you would need some mechanism (`ReleaseStrategy`) that would know when all expected replies are received.

Or you can simply receive the discrete replies and handle them individually.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54207780Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54207780Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("fanout", "", "foo", m -> {
            m.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo("replies");
            return m;
        });
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
    public String listen1(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue2")
    public String listen2(String in) {
        return in + in;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "replies")
    public void replyHandler(String reply) {
        System.out.println(reply);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanout() {
        return new FanoutExchange("fanout");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue1() {
        return new Queue("queue1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding1() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue1()).to(fanout());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue2() {
        return new Queue("queue2");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding2() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue2()).to(fanout());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue replies() {
        return new Queue("replies");
    }

}
```

and

```
FOO
foofoo
```

Comment: As I explained in the question- yes I am aware that convertSendAndReceive does not cut it. Hence the question - HOW can I listen to multiple replies?

Comment: As I said, use a listener container, or a @RabbitListener. See the documentation. Set the replyTo header.

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide an example? Your answer does not explain it at all

Comment: "some mechanism" or "see the documentation" is not exactly specific